# PHP - filtering and passing data into my app

Tags: php, scrape

I am very new to programming and need a little help with getting data from a website and passing it into my PHP script.

The website is http://www.birthdatabase.com/.

I would like to plug in a name (First and Last) and retrieve the result. I know you can query the site by passing the name in the URL, but I am having problems scraping the results.

http://www.birthdatabase.com/cgi-bin/query.pl?textfield=FIRST&textfield2=LAST&age=&affid=

I am using the file_get_contents($URL) function to get the page but need help after that. Specifically, I would like to scrape only the results from a certain state if there are multiple results for that name.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You wants to get data by php script?

Answer (score 0):

Read about `POST` method and its array (`$_POST`) ---> [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php).

Similarly, there is `GET` method as well.

Comment: I understand POST and GET methods. My question is more about filtering the data

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you see [POST](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KgTOKFgCKxM) AND [GET](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=ZMLkF1vmZdE?) method?